# How to send a second value via ajax to php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using ajax to search a db for values and populate a droplist. This is my ajax code:

```
function searchq6(){
    var searchstate = $("input[name='region']").val();
    var searchTxt = $("input[name='suburb']").val();
    $.post("search-suburb.php", {searchVal: searchTxt, st:searchstate})
    .done(function(sbb) {
        $("#sbb").html(sbb);
    }); 
}
```

Here, I'm getting a user entered region and searching the db for suburbs in that region. This is my php code:

```
$output = '' ;
if (isset($_POST['searchVal'])){
$searchq = $_POST['searchVal'];
$st = $_POST['st'];
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT DISTINCT title FROM `wp_locations` WHERE state='".$st."'  AND `title` LIKE  '%".$searchq."%' LIMIT 10")or     die("Could not search!");
if (!mysqli_query($link,$query))
{
        echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($link));
}
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($count == 0){
    $output = '<option>No results!</option>';
}else{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $suburb = $row['title'];
    $postcode = $row['postcode'];

?>
    <option value="<?php echo $suburb; ?>"><?php echo $suburb; ?>    </option>
<?php
} // while
} // else
} // main if
```

What I want to do is, to send the `postcode` value to a different input box. This is how my html looks

```
Suburb:* <input type="text" name="suburb" list="sbb" required size="30" value="<?php echo $suburb;  ?>" onkeyup="searchq6()" id="output">
        <datalist id="sbb" name="taskoption6" >
                <option> </option>
        </datalist>
Postcode:* <input type="number" name="postcode" required value="<?php echo $postcode;  ?>"  id="postcode">
```

Simply adding `$("#postcode").html(postcode);` does't work. How do I send the value from the php file?

Comment: Delete one double-quote, after `<?php echo $postcode;  ?>"` in last line in last code snippet.

Comment: @MedetAhmetsonAtabayev, that was a typo. corrected it in the question now

Comment: Why don't you send json as result from php?

Comment: @Abhishek how do I do that? And how do I get it back via ajax? I'm not very familiar with json

Comment: does each suburb returned by with AJAX request has different postcodes? And when suburb selected from `<datalist>`, input for postcode must show relevant value. Is it what you want?

Comment: @MedetAhmetsonAtabayev, yes the postcode is in the db too. and yes, that's what I want

Answer (score 0):

Just create an array having three values.
1. success true/false
2. data array of values if success true otherwise null
3. error reason why success value is false.

So, one of your error result will be:

```
$result = ['success' => false, 'data' => null, 'error' => 'error connecting db'];
```

And your success result will be:

```
$result = ['success'=> true, 'data'=> ['suburbs'=> $suburbs, 'pincode' => $pincode], 'error' => null];
```

now send this result array as json.

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

Then parse [Json in jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) and populate the reult where you it.

Comment: Do I have to use this format:

`$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});`
or can I use my same ajax function?

Comment: @YohanBlake you can use the same function, it will intelligently guess the format of the response.

Comment: but the thing in my case is, when returning the value, the suburbs is sent in the <option> tag so that it is loaded to select box. How can I return this AND the postcode?

Comment: Always avoid returning HTML in ajax response. Just parse the result and get the array of suburbs. Then populate your <option> tags using jquery.

Comment: I tried using `echo $suburb;` in the php file and just using `<option> </option> ` in the datalist, but it doesn't work. Can you show me the code on how to do it ?

Comment: Ok. First of all do what I said and console the data from your jquery and tell me what you are getting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110946/discussion-between-yohan-blake-and-abhishek).

Answer (score 0):

In the PHP file:

```
// Output is array, will be send as JSON data
$output = array("suburbs"=>'', "postcodes"=>array());

if (isset($_POST['searchVal'])){
    $searchq = $_POST['searchVal'];
    $st = $_POST['st'];
    $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT DISTINCT title FROM `wp_locations`     WHERE state='".$st."'  AND `title` LIKE  '%".$searchq."%'     LIMIT 10")or     die("Could not search!");
    if (!mysqli_query($link,$query)) {
        echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($link));
    }
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($count == 0){
        $output["suburbs"] = '<option>No results!</option>';
    }else{
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            $suburb = $row['title'];
            $postcode = $row['postcode'];
            $output["suburbs"] .= "<option value=\"$suburb\">$suburb  </option>";
            $output["postcodes"][$suburb] = $postcode;
        } // while
    } // else
    // Send result
    echo json_encode($output);
} // main if
```

In AJAX part of HTML:

```
// Make global variable that holds POSTCODES:
var postcodes = {};
function searchq6(){
    var searchstate = $("input[name='region']").val();
    var searchTxt = $("input[name='suburb']").val();
    $.post("search-suburb.php", {searchVal: searchTxt, st:searchstate})
    .done(function(response) {
        var responseObj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
        $("#sbb").html(responseObj["suburbs"]);
        postcodes = responseObj["postcodes"];
    }); 
}
```

In HTML:

```
 Suburb:* <input type="text" onselect="change_post(this)" onchange="change_post(this)" name="suburb" list="sbb" required size="30"  value="<?php echo $suburb;  ?>" onkeyup="searchq6()" id="output">
    <datalist id="sbb" name="taskoption6" >
            <option> </option>
    </datalist>
 Postcode:* <input type="number" name="postcode" required value="<?php echo $postcode;  ?>"  id="postcode">
 <script>
      //var postcodes = { "1":"First", "2":"Second", "3":"Third", "4":"Fourth" };
        function change_post(out) {
            //console.log(postcodes[ out.value ]!=undefined);
            if ( postcodes[ out.value ]!=undefined )
                document.getElementById("postcode").innerHTML = postcodes[ out.value ];
        }
 </script>
```

Comment: I get a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token E` in the console

Comment: Can you add `console.log(response);` inside .done() event function, and put here what does it show?

Comment: `Error description: {"suburbs":"<option value=\"FOOTSCRAY\">FOOTSCRAY  <\/option><option value=\"WEST FOOTSCRAY\">WEST FOOTSCRAY  <\/option>","postcodes":{"FOOTSCRAY":null,"WEST FOOTSCRAY":null}}`

Comment: When you get an SyntaxError? After clicking one function?

Comment: Can you talk in chant?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111066/discussion-between-medet-ahmetson-atabayev-and-yohan-blake).